# How to use the do_action () with parameter

Tags: functions, actions

I am trying to trigger an action in *functions.php* with the `do_action()` function, but I appear to need an attribute.

The following

```
do_action( 'really_simple_share button="facebook_like"');
```

does not  work...

Can you tell me the proper way to make it work (I have tried many other things that did not work either).

Comment: do you mean do_shortcode('[really_simple_share button="facebook_like"]'); ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way is to pass first argument as a unique string which acts as an identifier for the action & any additional arguments after that

```
do_action('unique_action_tag', $parameter1, $parameter2,,,, & so on);
```

To attach functions to this action you'll do

```
// 10 is the priority, higher means executed first
// 2 is number of arguments the function can accept
add_action('unique_action_tag', 'my_custom_function', 10, 2)
function my_custom_function($param1, $param2) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: ca you do it with MY action ?

Comment: You mean `$button = 'facebook_like'; do_action('really_simple_share', $button);`. Then in "functions.php" `add_action('really_simple_share', 'my_function');
function my_function($button) {
    // do something
}`

Comment: Thank you - this was helpful. I found the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22218), there is a sample approach to work around this.